# Can Matrix class object hold Bitmap object of Image?

Tags: c#, graphics, matrix

Can `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix` class object hold bitmap object of Image?

e.g. Graphics object can hold it.

Comment: How do you mean hold? It is not holding, this line is creating the Graphics object Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *can*, but you have to implement all. Matrix is just an information holder, what is inside of it, and how it managed by those ones who read it, is up to developer.

Also according to documentation, as @spender pointed out there is a size limitation: only 3x3.

So general answer is: *yes, you can*, but there is no much sense of doing that, imo.

Comment: @Aabha: sure. There is no any *native* support for in this context. Matrix (in general) is 2 dimensional array, and nothing else. In this concrete case its 2d array with 3x3, suitable for 2D transformation (X Axis, Y Axis and Offset information)

Answer (score 2):

No. From the docs:

> Encapsulates a 3-by-3 affine matrix that represents a geometric transform.

I suppose you could store a 3x3pixel monochrome image in one, but it would be an abuse.